# Can I use highcharts in a pdf generate with prawn in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, highcharts, prawn, execjs

In my rails application, I use highcharts to display some charts. And now, I need to generate a pdf with charts (I will use prawn).
I want to know if I can use highcharts in my pdf. Maybe with ExecJS ? Or with an alternative to prawn ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to render the javascript charts as a PDF

This blog post is helpful: http://www.claytonlz.com/index.php/2011/02/broken-highcharts-wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: wkhtmltopdf seems to be a little tricky for me! Is there another way ? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need a full browser automation "thing" that can print to PDF.

Comment: In this case, I'll try wkhtmltopdf ^^ Thanks!