# Highcharts and Prawn in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has anyone had any success using Highcharts with Prawn? Is there a way to include the generated jpg or png to insert into the Prawn code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896182/can-i-use-highcharts-in-a-pdf-generate-with-prawn-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert images in prawn code by using image tag

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),
                               %w[.. example_helper]))

filename = File.basename(__FILE__).gsub('.rb', '.pdf')
Prawn::Example.generate(filename) do
  text "The image will go right below this line"
  image "#{Prawn::DATADIR}/images/pigs.jpg"
end
```

Comment: Thanks vibha, I guess my next question is, how can I grab the image from high charts as it creates it dynamically?

Comment: Hi @DollarChills - Did you find the answer of your question that 'how can I grab the image from high charts as it creates it dynamically?'.If yes, then please let me know because i have the similar kind of problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes i did @ShoaibMalik