# Spider Chart (High Chart) in rails with Prawn PDF How to generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, highcharts, prawn, spider-chart

I want to implement a spider chart (High chart) in my rails application inside pdf for PDF I've used Prawn PDF gem. So anyone has any idea about implementing a spider chart in pdf. I also have a reference screenshot of the high chart spider chart the same chart I want to implement in my rails app pdf thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can find on the SO forum a lot of users suggest to use wkhtmltopdf to do it. Suggested solutions:

- [Can I use highcharts in a pdf generate with prawn in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896182/can-i-use-highcharts-in-a-pdf-generate-with-prawn-in-rails)
- [Wkhtmltopdf fails to printing SVG path (highchart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340/wkhtmltopdf-fails-to-printing-svg-path-highchart)
- [Using wkhtmltopdf with highcharts shows blank chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106434/using-wkhtmltopdf-with-highcharts-shows-blank-chart)

And here is an example of how to create a spider chart in the JavaScript which you should easily rebuild in your project:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1e0pmtv/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'test',
    data: [43000, 19000, 60000],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }],
});
```

I am also attaching the link to the blog with instruction of implementing Highcharts with Ruby.

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/i-am-ruby-developer-how-can-i-use-highcharts/

Answer (score 0):

There's [prawn-svg](https://github.com/mogest/prawn-svg) that can render SVGs into prawn, and so you can make a svg graph and render it inside your pdf.

Highcharts can export SVGs, but to run you should have a javascript runtime, which is possible, but will take some effort to setup and run. So some ruby-level chart library may be more preferable (it you can find one, as most current charting libraries are for client side javacsript).

Easier solution is to use a html-to-pdf converter, like `wkhtmltopdf`, that popupar `wicked-pdf` gem is based on. It runs a headless browser, renders the page and exports to pdf. The process is much slower, because for each pdf a separate process with browser in it has to run, and resulting pdf is larger, but you can use familiar web techniques in markup and reuse html views.